# How to query DB Browser for SQLite with user input in a Python program?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a Python program that takes user input to create a database with the DB Browser for SQLite. The issue I'm having is trying to take the user input variable 'title' and using it to query the database to see if a specific book is already in the database. Then joining the tables together so the results can be printed. I've tried multiple methods of getting the user input to work correctly, this is the latest try. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    def query_book(title):
        query_1 = '''SELECT Book.title, Author.name, Genre.name, Book.copyright, Book.read 
                  WHERE Book.title = ? FROM Book JOIN Author JOIN Genre JOIN MultipleAuthors ON 
                  MultipleAuthors.book_id = Book.id AND MultipleAuthors.author_id = Author.id
                  ORDER BY Book.title, Author.name DESC
                  '''

        formatted_rows = list()
        for row in cur.execute(query_1, (title,)):
```

Comment: DB browser has nothing to do here. Replace `?` with an actual title (in quotes) and see if you get expected results.

Comment: And don't forget to [fetch the data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone)

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for replying. I think it's fetching the data ok, I previously had the JOIN working fine when it was retrieving all the records without user input. I did try to hardcode the title within the statement, no success. I did manage to get it to retrieve the record based on user input once I removed the rest of the JOIN statement. So it seems like I can have either a user input search without a JOIN, or a JOIN without user input, but I cannot get them both working inside the statement at the same time.